# Can a cherry picked Git commit have same commit ID (without using rebase)

Tags: git

I am new to Git.

I have a branch called Master and another called Development.

If a branch called 'feature-request-1' is merged to Master then I want to cherry pick this commit into Development so that the commit ID is same in both Master and Development.

In my local machine I did following steps:

1. git checkout Development
2. git cherry-pick <commit ID of Master>

Now the commit is present in Development but the commit ID is different.

Azure DevOps web interface Branches page now shows Development branch is 1 commit behind Master and 1 commit ahead of Master even though both are in sync in-terms of content so this is confusing.

Comment: Short answer to the title question: **No, definitely not.** By design. (since the hash is produced from the commit metadata which contain, between other things, a timestamp.)

Comment: "then I want to cherry pick this commit into Development so that the commit ID is same in both Master and Development" You cannot. Stop wanting that. "Now the commit is present in Development but the commit ID is different." That is expected, based on what Git is and what cherry pick is. There seems to be no question to answer. All is well. Keep calm and carry on.

Comment: git is a content-addressed filesystem with a version control skin. Things are addressed via sha-1 hashes. If you had two different things with the same hash, it would lead to problems. Why are the two commits different things? They are probably anchored to a different parent (which also counts for the hash). If you merge or rebase and those two meet on the same branch, git will notice the identical contents and ignore one of them (/merge them/do the right thing etc.).

Comment: @teapot418 No, Git will not throw one of them away. Or ignore one of them. It won't look directly at their contents at all. That is not how merge logic works.

Comment: The most useful solution in this case is probably to merge Master into Development. In my workflow, to cherry-pick commits is a tool for exceptional situations rather than for regular development.

Comment: As you mentioned "in sync in-terms of content", note that `git cherry-pick $commit` merely applies the patch of a commit. It does not guarantee that the code of the new commit will be the same with the code of the original commit. Furthermore, the patch of the original commit and the patch of the new commit are not always the same even when there is not any conflict. Pay special attention to it if you want to cherry-pick a commit to different branches.

Comment: @j6t I agree; regular/frequent use of cherry-pick to me has a workflow smell.

Answer (score 2):

As @Romain mentioned in his comment, if you cherry-pick a commit it will always appear as a *new* commit with a different SHA-1 hash.  This is by design, because Git needs to mark that the commit is different than the original, even if functionally it is the same.

However, there might be a way to achieve what you want, using a Git rebase.  Consider the following branch setup:

```
master:  A -- B -- C
               \
feature:        D
```

If you wanted to bring in the exact `C` commit, with the same SHA-1 hash, you could do a rebase:

```
# from feature
git rebase origin/master
```

This would result in:

```
master:  A -- B -- C
                    \
feature:             D'
```

Now the `feature` branch has the same commit from `master`, with its previous `D` commit itself being rewritten to a new commit, with a new SHA-1 hash.